# Spring: Implementing Update method to save modified value in to db

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a save method through which i am saving my data from UI to the db for that i have created bean type Product

```
  public ResponseEntity<String> saveProduct(@RequestBody final Product product)
 {
  returnValue = productService.updateProduct(product);
 }
```

Above method is working correctly. Additionally i have just added one more update method that will update only modified field. So for this i created a separate bean class

```
    public class DynamicProductUpdate
    {

      /** The DynamicUpdate id. */
       private String id;

       private Date effectiveDate;

      /** The DynamicUpdate field To . */
       private Map<String, Object> fieldsToBeUpdate;

       private String userId;

     }
```

My Update method-

```
  public ResponseEntity<String> updateProduct(@RequestBody final DynamicUpdate dynamicUpdate)
 {
  returnValue = prodService.updateProduct(dynamicUpdate);
 }
```

from UI side am passing the updated field as a key value pair. But

```
         dynamicUpdate value is showing null.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the complete error log.

Comment: @KaranVerma I dont really get any error in that.. when i tried to pass the vallue , dynamicUpdate is showing null. It should hold all the updated value

Comment: We'd need to see what the code in prodService.updateProduct is doing to have any chance of helping.